# Angular and IE9 stupidity where native methods

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-9, q

In Angular 1.2.0, there is this funny comment:

> // IE stupidity! (IE doesn't have apply for some native functions)

It sits on line 9835 in the functionCall function:

```
  functionCall: function(fn, contextGetter) {
    var argsFn = [];
    if (this.peekToken().text !== ')') {
      do {
        argsFn.push(this.expression());
      } while (this.expect(','));
    }
    this.consume(')');

    var parser = this;

    return function(scope, locals) {
      var args = [];
      var context = contextGetter ? contextGetter(scope, locals) : scope;

      for (var i = 0; i < argsFn.length; i++) {
        args.push(argsFn[i](scope, locals));
      }
      var fnPtr = fn(scope, locals, context) || noop;

      ensureSafeObject(context, parser.text);
      ensureSafeObject(fnPtr, parser.text);

      // IE stupidity! (IE doesn't have apply for some native functions)
      var v = fnPtr.apply
            ? fnPtr.apply(context, args)
            : fnPtr(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4]);

      return ensureSafeObject(v, parser.text);
    };
  },
```

I believe it is causing me pain, but no errors are thrown so I'm having a hard time seeing exactly **what** native function it might be trying (and failing) to call apply on. Ever since I implemented $q library to use promises to handle async REST calls, IE9 doesn't even make an attempt to call the services (according to the network tab in dev tools). Instead, the promise is immediately rejected. I tried googling for an answer, and looking at angular's [docs on using IE](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie), but I'm getting nowhere.

Has anyone had a similar issue with getting promises to work on IE9 using angular's "q-lite"? Does anyone know what this silly comment is referring to specifically?

Comment: Do you have an example of your code that is not working - even better could you put it in a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/)? The comment is referring to [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) being absent for some built in functions in IE9, making them awkward to call. I can't see it being related.

Comment: @Andyrooger I'm sorry, in this case I can't provide code. The app is huge, internal, and as I'm not entirely sure what IE9 is objecting to,  I haven't the foggiest what part of the code to mock into a plunkr. I was wondering if anyone knew what specific native functions the comment refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *believe* I figured it out through a ton of trial and error. It seems the issue, in my case, was that I was using the built-in `q` library for promises... specifically `q.all([])`:

```
$q.all([
  firstRequest.$promise,
  secondRequest.$promise,
  thirdRequest.$promise,
  moreRequets.$promise
]).then(function() {
  //do stuff
});
```

While I still have not found out what specific operations the angular code refers to when it says `some native functions`, I found that the [docs for function.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) have the following caveat:

> Note: Most browsers, including Chrome 14 and Internet Explorer 9, still do not accept array-like objects and will throw an exception.

Whatever the specifics, removing my reference to `$q.all` solved it for me. I hope this helps anyone who has this issue in the future. If someone happens to encounter another case where this IE behavior chokes up angular, perhaps they would be so kind as to comment below or add an answer.

FYI, I am currently at angular 1.2.14.

Comment: I use object like version of $q.all in my Angular (1.2.21) app, and I still getting this error.

Comment: @mrzepinski Are you in IE9? We have since migrated to IE10 and I have not noticed this issue anymore, even though we use q.all(). Either IE fixed the problem in v10 or something else was causing it.

Comment: Yes, I am using IE9. This is the latest IE version, which we supported.

Comment: You say you removed your reference to $q.all. What did you do instead?

Comment: I meant that if I removed that code I no longer got the error. I never had to code a workaround because we ended up moving to IE10. Off the top of my head (so maybe not the best solution) I suppose I could have tried to chain the promises together like so
Instead of:
`$q.all([
 accountInfoResource,
 personalInfoResource,
 physicalAddressResource]).then(function() ...);`
I get: **untested / pseudo-code**
`accountInfoResource
.then(personalInfoResource)
.then(physicalAddressResource)`

Comment: Sorry, took too long and couldn't edit comment.
Off the top of my head (so maybe not the best solution) I suppose I could have tried to chain the promises together like so
Instead of:
`$q.all([
 accountInfoResource,
 personalInfoResource,
 physicalAddressResource]).then(function() ...);`
I get: **untested / pseudo-code**
`accountInfoResource
.then(personalInfoResource)
.then(physicalAddressResource).then(function() {//do something after everything resolves...}`.

Comment: @JoeGillon Or I could maybe write a factory that accepts an array of promises or resources and a function to execute once they are all resolved.  That would be a much easier thing to unit test. Maybe something with a signature of `promiseService.executeAfterAll([promise1, promise2, promise3, function() {console.log("all are done!"});`.